# Is it possible to get the original location after mocking GPS location, with mock mode ON?

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, mocking, location

1) Is it possible to get the original present location coordinates from ANDROID LOCATION SERVICES after mocking GPS location, with mock mode ON ?

This location should be got without making the mock mode OFF.

Else, 
2) I need to disable the location services GPS for a while, turning on and off mock location.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, from Google doc http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html

> To turn off mock mode while the location client is connected, call
>   LocationClient.setMockMode(false).